# Why doesn't my MOSFET switch off?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

In the following circuit, `LEDPWR` goes the power lines of some digitally addressable LEDs. But the LEDs are not always on, and even when they are not being lit, they are consuming about half a milliamp each, which will drain the battery over a few days even if it's not in use.

I was under the impression that I could use a MOSFET like a switch. So the micro-controller could simply set the gate to `LOW` and the LEDs would no longer be connected to power and would not drain the battery when not in active use.

This is the circuit I devised.

[image]

But it doesn't work like I expected. When I pull the gate LOW, current appears to continue to flow, and the LEDs continue to draw power. Why?

I tested each prong of the transistor with a multimeter in both the on and off states and found that despite the gate being LOW, I'm getting voltage on the drain. Here's what I measured:

**ON**

- Gate: 4.20V
- Source: 4.36V
- Drain: 3.73V
- Current: ~18mA

**OFF**

- Gate: 0V
- Source: 4.11V
- Drain: 3.51V
- Current: ~5mA

If I disconnect the LED power wire in the OFF state, current plummets to less than 0.1mA, so the MOSFET is clearly not doing what I expect.

So first, **how do I get my MOSFET to actually turn disconnect the source and drain?**

And second, **why am I seeing a 0.6V loss at the drain?** With a single cell LiPo (3.7-4.2V) as a power source, that's a lot.

My MOSFET's datasheet: MOSFET datasheet: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/2N7002P.pdf

Comment: Your mosfet is upside down.
Look at the body diode in the schematic, see ? It's forward biased, that explains the 0.6v drop.

Comment: Is it? I thought I read that the source should be your power, and the drain should be the load, which matches my footprint and schematic, I think.

Comment: source -> power and drain -> load is a configuration of a P-Channel mosfet, what you have is an N-Channel mosfet.
http://brunningsoftware.co.uk/Pictures/U-fig10.jpg

Comment: Well crap. These pcbs are boned then :( So if I swap the source and the drain, you think this will work like I expected? If so, add an answer as such and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MOSFET is "upside down" as Mike said.

BUT

3 "fixes":

1. Use P Channel FETs and all shall be wellish.

FET will be on when gate is LOW (~= 0 V).
FET will be off when gate is HIGH(~= 4.1V)

---

2. IF you can isolate the MOSFET 4.1V and gnd feeds from the rest of the PCB by cutting tracks then

   - Swap MOSFET 4.1V and ground
   - Reverse LED polarity

---

3. Depending on pads:

Take MOSFET

Bend leads UP

Invert MOSFET - solder MOSFET D to old S pad

Solder MOSFET S to old D pad.

Solder MOSFET G to G pad.

Or use wire tacked on leads to make it easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just spent some time on solution 3 with a hot rework station and the bastard finally went in, but by now I think I cooked it. Penance for my mistake, surely. :P